# Tool to report rest interfaces

Tags: spring, rest, jersey

We have a web application using Jersey and Spring's rest template. Does anyone know of a tool that can scan a code base and produce a report that lists all exposed endpoints and also internal references to those endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also take a look at [Swagger](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/), a  framework for describing, producing, consuming, and visualizing RESTful web services.

Swagger supports multiple REST frameworks and also [JAX-RS based on Jersey](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs).

From their [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki):

> The Swagger framework simultaneously addresses server, client, and documentation/sandbox needs for REST APIs. As a specification, it is language-agnostic. It also provides a long runway into new technologies and protocols beyond HTTP.
>
> With Swagger's declarative resource specification, clients can understand and consume services without knowledge of server implementation or access to the server code. The Swagger UI framework allows both developers and non-developers to interact with the API in a sandbox UI that gives clear insight into how the API responds to parameters and options. Swagger happily speaks both JSON and XML, with additional formats in the works.

Answer (score 1):

Jersey can provide a WADL report at the /application.wadl URI. It doesn't document complex types but at least gives you a list of endpoints.

See https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/WADL